Is Firebase checking some routes when connecting a new domain?
I noticed very weird API calls just after connecting a new domain to Firebase.
The client (Go-http-client) tried to access a lot of routes like /web.config, /config.xml, /.ssh/id_rsa, /wp-admin/setup-config.php, and so on and so forth...
I am pretty sure that it is some random checks from a hacker.
What is weird though is that the IP addresses are somehow identified as Google ones (though one website identifies it as a proxy server).
Does somebody know if there is any chance it might come from a legit service in Google?

firebaser here
I don't think Firebase is scanning any specific routes, and for example /wp-admin/setup-config.php is not something I'd expect to find in our codebase.
It could be the general Google crawler, or some other crawler that monitors public resources - like the certificate that your site gets added to automatically.

I find it weird though that Google crawlers might query routes like /.ssh/id_rsa
